# Silverlight CheckBox Results

Tags: silverlight, checkbox

I'm a little new to Silverlight. I have about 12 CheckBoxes on a page. What I want to accomplish is, when the user clicks on a button, it must return which CheckBoxes have all been checked. And I also need the Content of the CheckBox.

I have thought of adding the same Checked Event to all of the CheckBoxes etc, but from there I'm not really entirely sure where I'm going with it.

Any suggestions?

I have a class that contains string properties which at this point correlates to the Checkboxes...This is just the way I started, not sure if it's right.

```
public class Categories : Base
{
    #region Constructor

    public Categories()
    {

    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Properties

    private string _CategoryOne = default(string);
    private string _CategoryTwo = default(string);
    private string _CategoryThree = default(string);
    private string _CategoryFour = default(string);
    private string _CategoryFive = default(string);        

    #endregion

    #region Public Properties

    public string CategoryOne
    {
        get { return _CategoryOne; }
        set
        {
            _CategoryOne = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CategoryOne");
        }
    }

    public string CategoryTwo
    {
        get { return _CategoryTwo; }
        set
        {
            _CategoryTwo = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CategoryTwo");
        }
    }

    public string CategoryThree
    {
        get { return _CategoryThree; }
        set
        {
            _CategoryThree = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CategoryThree");
        }
    }

    public string CategoryFour
    {
        get { return _CategoryFour; }
        set
        {
            _CategoryFour = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CategoryFour");
        }
    }

    public string CategoryFive
    {
        get { return _CategoryFive; }
        set
        {
            _CategoryFive = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CategoryFive");
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Xaml:

```
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Margin="5,1,1,1"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <CheckBox Content="Category One"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                      Margin="1,1,3,1" />
```

My xaml looks the same for each CheckBox(5). Then I just have a button on the page. And when the User clicks this button I want to know which Checkboxes have been checked (ie CateogryOne, CategoryThree and CategoryFour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is what @HiTech suggested through databinding. If want to do in code-behind as you are trying to do (which I don't recommend) it can be done as:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">        
    <CheckBox Content="Test 1"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Test 2"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Test 3"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Test 4"/>
    <Button Content="Click" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And the click event:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in this.LayoutRoot.Children)
    {
        var checkbox = item as CheckBox;
        if (checkbox != null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0} is {1}", checkbox.Content, checkbox.IsChecked);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: The correct way.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">        
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Content="Click" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And binding code:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{

    private ObservableCollection<CheckBoxItem> items = new ObservableCollection<CheckBoxItem>();

    public ObservableCollection<CheckBoxItem> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.items;
        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.items.Add(new CheckBoxItem() {Name = "Test 1", IsChecked = true});
        this.items.Add(new CheckBoxItem() {Name = "Test 2", IsChecked = false});
        this.items.Add(new CheckBoxItem() {Name = "Test 3", IsChecked = false});
        this.items.Add(new CheckBoxItem() {Name = "Test 4", IsChecked = true});
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0} is {1}", item.Name, item.IsChecked);
        }
    }

    public class CheckBoxItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks this definitely looks like something that will work for me. It's a small app so this is perfect. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Melanie: note: The properties should be notify properties if the twoway binding is to accept external updates, but anivas' basic version will do for a list of checkboxes that does nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of checkboxes, bound to a collection of objects containing your check property.

Then you are just iterating the collection for all the ones with a Checked value of true. You can bind the display text to a second property if that is what you mean by "content" of the checkbox.

**Note: for the bindings to work properly (accept external updates) the category properties have to be notify properties.*

### CategoryView.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace PersonTests
{
    public partial class CategoryView : UserControl
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        public CategoryView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>()
                                {
                                    new Category() {CategoryName = "Category 1"},
                                    new Category() {CategoryName = "Category 2"},
                                    new Category() {CategoryName = "Category 3"},
                                    new Category() {CategoryName = "Category 4"}
                                };
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var checkedCategories = from c in Categories
                                    where c.Checked
                                    select c;
            foreach (var category in checkedCategories)
            {
                // Do something with the selected categories
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### CategoryView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="PersonTests.CategoryView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Click" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding CategoryName}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

### Category.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace PersonTests
{
    public class Category : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private bool _checked;
        public bool Checked
        {
            get { return _checked; }
            set
            {
                if (_checked != value)
                {
                    _checked = value;
                    SendPropertyChanged("Checked");
                }
            }
        }

        private string _categoryName;
        public string CategoryName
        {
            get { return _categoryName; }
            set
            {
                if (_categoryName != value)
                {
                    _categoryName = value;
                    SendPropertyChanged("CategoryName");
                }
            }
        }

        public virtual void SendPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: great answer, full code really helps. Definitely want to use binding when you do this, not code behind.