# Binding to property of object that is created by thread working at background

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, binding, mvvm

I use MVVM pattern in my multithreading WPF app.

Now in the model I have (I skipped the obvious implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged interface to make it more clear):

```
public class ShallowModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string _dbState;
  public string DbState
  {
     get { return _dbState; }
     set 
     { 
       _dbState = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("DbState") // ofc there is implementation of this
     }
  }
  private InsideObject _inObject;
  public InsideObject InObject
  {
     get { return _inObject; }
     set 
     { 
       _inObject = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("InObject") 
     }
  }
}   

public class InsideModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string _actState;
  public string ActState
  {
     get { return _actState; }
     set 
     { 
       _actState= value;
       OnPropertyChanged("ActState")
     }
  }
}
```

Say I have TextBlocks on the View:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding ActObjectState}/>
<TextBlock Text={Binding DbState}/>
```

Now there's a part of problematic ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private ShallowModel _model;
  public string ActObjectState
  {
     get 
     { 
       if(_model.InObject != null)
         return _model.InObject.ActState; 
       else
         return null;
     }
  }
  public string DbState
  {
     get 
     { 
       return _model.DbState;
     }
  }
}
```

The problem is that ActObjectState and DbState are not being updated when background thread is updating properties of ShallowModel and/or InsideModel. My questions are:

1. Should I add Model public property to ViewModel and bind view like *{Binding Path=Model.DbState}*? I think it disrupts the MVVM idea - View shouldnt know about Model.
2. InObject in ShallowModel is created by a new thread after User click button on UI. Therefore when ViewModel is created InObject is null. Somehow - after it's created by the thread - ActObjectState is not updated. How to make it work? Make binding like {Binding Path=Model.InObject.ActState}? This implies the need of having knowledge about Model by UI designer.

Thx, sry for my english

Comment: This should definitely help you [inherit INotifyPropertyChanged ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871952/silverlight-checkbox-results

Comment: I'm not sure what are you refering to exactly. Whole INotifyPropertyChanged interface is implemented. Should it be used also in ViewModel, even if these properties are not set by the ViewModel but Model - both of them are set as a result of action of a background thread.

Comment: You're showing all the wrong code. Your problem is with updating the UI with bound properties, yet you don't show the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged. You say a background thread is updating these properties, yet you don't show the code for it.

Comment: Of course, ViewModel has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged too (and if you are updating cross-thread, you have to use some sort of safe invoker that will post events to the right synchronization context). Your bindings bind to the ViewModel, right? how will they know that the model's properties have changed?

Comment: @o_q - I thought implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged interface is pretty obvious. I took it from Josh Smith MVVM framework (my ViewModel inherit form his WorkspaceViewModel class).

Comment: @AntonTykhyy - Model also implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface. I thought - model notifies ViewModel and ViewModel notifies View. Is that not true?

Comment: Just implementing INotifyPropertyChanged is not enough. Your viewmodel needs to register for model's property change notifications and re-raise the relevant events on itself.

Comment: @Joe my point is that your problem is not in the code you're showing, so it's difficult to understand what's wrong

Comment: @AntonTykhyy - do you have link or sth that shows how to register class for other class notifications?

Comment: No, I don't. I think it would be easier for you to just bind to the model directly. In this case the binding engine will do all the work of tracking property changes, subscribing and unsubscribing event handlers etc. It is quite a mess to do by hand.

Comment: BTW, you don't register _classes_ for notifications. Every viewmodel _object_ needs to register for its model object's property change notifications (`model.PropertyChanged += ...`), track changes to `Model.InObject` in the handler and register for changes _in the inner object_ (not forgetting to unregister the old handler) to track changes to `ActState` and raise the viewmodel `PropertyChanged` event. Plus you need to use weak listeners to avoid memory leaks, etc. People write whole _frameworks_ to deal with all this stuff.

Comment: Ok, You convienced me to bind to the model. I have the feeling, that binding engine is not the best too, because when I bind to some properties, that are null while binding, they tend to not being updated later. Still, this is another topic i guess. Thx for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would take your suggestion 1. its the easiest way and i dont see any violation of the MVVM pattern.

if this not works for you - you have to put the view related logic in your viewmodel. so maybe its necessary that the viewmodel listen to the changes of the model and rethrow(with the view related logic) these changes to the view.

when working with threads be aware of dispatcher stuff, but i think you know that

Comment: I use dispatcher, invoking, etc. when its needed. Thx. I need the UI to be updated by model. So I could put some model logic to viewmodel and I bet it would work. My 1. suggestion seems kind of dirty for me.

Comment: In the end I took my suggestion #1 because of lack of ideas (or time to implement sth like Anton Tykhyy was writing about). Thanks all of you tough.

Answer (score 0):

If your thread created the ShallowModel you need to raise all properties that are related to that on the viewmodel. You can raise a `String.Empty` to tell the databinding engine to fetch all bound properties. But because you are in a thread you cant just fire the `PropertyChangedEvent` you need to dispatch it, so the UI Thread can handle it. What we did, was to make our Raise Method ui thread safe with the [dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx).

Comment: Actually ShallowObject is passed to ViewModel. The InsideObject is created by the thread. There are no errors, exceptions. It's just not update. While waiting for some answers - I have built some simple app where all processes are done by UI thread. It wasn't working. || By raising you mean set property in ViewModel to `String.Empty`?

Comment: @Joe Just a small thing ... is this a Typo? AstState
!= ActState.

Comment: Yea, sorry for that. Corrected.